# Talend: How can I set global variable into tREST HTTP Headers?

Tags: java, rest, global-variables, key-value, talend

I run a job to refresh token to get new access token every time the scheduled job executed. Then, the json response of the new access token is set as global variable.

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| "myKey" | "access_token" |

Question is, how can I call the global variable to set as value for Authorization for next API endpoint call?

[image: tREST Job]

It is Zoho provided API, it needs Authorization with "Zoho-oauthtoken *-access_token-*".
So I need it to concate with global variable that I set before. Is the calling expression is right?

Comment: Use globalMap.get("token") or if you use context.var if you are putting your value in a context

Comment: could you show us how you are storing your global Variable so that we can help ?

Answer (score 2):

In the "value" field , call the global variable with syntax : `"Zoho-oauthtoken "+((String)globalMap.get("access_token"))`

globalMap is an object representing a key/value table, key being a string, value being an object.
To get the value linked to a key , you need to cast the 'object' returned by the 'get' method.